# Read Output From A Running Process Realtime (Command Prompt)

Tags: process, cmd, output, prompt

I have been researching for an answer for my question for a long while using Google and changing what words I use in-case I find my answer, I have had no luck.

What I want is to the read the output from a process in real-time, not when it finishes the command it has been given. I have a command that I use which doesn't end unless the user ends it manually, closes the form or an error occurs. So every timer interval I would like to read the output from the command prompt (process).
I use background workers to start the process so it doesn't interfere with the form if that is any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What platform/OS are you using? What do you want to do with the output? Why do you want to read it on a timer and not when it generates output?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 but I want it to work on other Windows computers since this program will be distributed. I want to read the output into a TextBox. I'm not entirely focuses on using it on a timer but I wouldn't mind getting the output when it's updated/changed.

Comment: Do you have control over the program that starts the process that generates the output you want to capture - I mean can you change it? And what language is it written in?

Comment: I start up a command prompt using Process.Start and I pass through arguments to it if that is what you mean. Also the command prompt accesses a file on the user's computer which is written in ruby (.rb).